# Determining countably finite, finite, or uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I determine whether the set of all differentiable functions is countably infinite, finite or uncountable?

I want to say it is equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$, so it is countable? And I know it is infinite but I'm not sure how to prove this also.

Comment: Try to show continuum many differentiable functions.

Comment: To continue the above hint, and you associate to each real number a differentiable function? It doesn't even need to be unique; just at least one.

Comment: Showing it's at least uncountable is very easy using pjs36's hint. Showing an upper bound is considerably more complicated.

Comment: Also I'm guessing you mean uncountably infinite instead of uncountably finite.